# Using a loop to populate a matrix in TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, tensorflow

So I'm trying to populate a matrix in TensorFlow, the size of this matrix changes depending on the inputs so I'm using TensorArray to do it. Essentially, the Numpy equivalent of this is:

```
areas = np.zeros((len(rows)-1,len(cols)-1))
for r in range(len(rows)-1):
    for c in range(len(cols)-1):
        areas[r,c] = (rows[r+1]-rows[r])*(cols[c+1]-cols[c])
```

I tried to implement this in TensorFlow using `tf.while_loop` and `tf.TensorArray`:

```
i = tf.constant(0)
areas = tf.TensorArray(dtype='float32', size=length_rc-1)
while_condition = lambda i, rows, areas: tf.less(i, length_rc-1)
def row_loop(i, rows, areas):        
    j = tf.constant(0)
    area = tf.TensorArray(dtype='float32', size=length_rc-1)
    while_condition = lambda j, cols, area: tf.less(j, length_rc-1)

    def col_loop(j, cols, area):
        area = area.write(j, tf.multiply(tf.subtract(rows[i+1],rows[i]),tf.subtract(cols[j+1],cols[j])))
        return [tf.add(j,1), cols, area]

    r = tf.while_loop(while_condition, col_loop, [j, cols, areas])
    areas = areas.write(i, r[2].stack())
    return [tf.add(i, 1), rows, areas]

# do the loop:
r = tf.while_loop(while_condition, row_loop, [i, rows, areas])
areas = r[2].stack()

p = sess.run([areas], feed_dict={pred_batch: pred, gt_batch: gt})
```

However, it does not seem to work and I'm not sure why. As you can see my code is similar to this post:
[Howe TensorArray and while_loop work together in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849693/howe-tensorarray-and-while-loop-work-together-in-tensorflow)

But it does not seem to work, anyone know what the issue is? The specific error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: Inconsistent shapes: saw (?,) but expected () (and infer_shape=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the tiny bug:

```
# do the loop:
r = tf.while_loop(while_condition, row_loop, [i, rows, areas])
areas = r[2].stack()
```

My input to `tf.while_loop` was incorrect, it should have been `area` instead of `areas`. Other than that, this is a valid way to do a nested loop to populate a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work? What do you expect to happen versus what actually happens?

For one thing, your loop condition looks off by 1 in both cases. In the first case, you will miss the last row and the last column, since `range` only produces values *less* than its argument.

Similarly, in the second case, your condition is `tf.less(i, length_rc-1)`: you probably want `i` to be equal to `length_rc-1` in the last iteration, not less than it. The condition should be `tf.less(i, length_rc)`.

Comment: Ah, the subtraction by 1 was intentional, I do not want to get the last element as in my code I have `rows[r+1]`, so I need to go to the second last element. Also, updated the post with the error!

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701631/tensorflow-while-loop-with-tensorarray